# Continuity of the feasible set of a linear problem with linear constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, linear-programming, implicit-function-theorem

Let ${\Omega}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be the set:

$ {\Omega}(t)= \{ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} : \boldsymbol{A}(t) \boldsymbol{x} =\boldsymbol{b},   c_1<x_i<c_2  \} $

where $\boldsymbol{A}(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$  is always full row rank, and the elements of $\boldsymbol{A}$ depends continously on the time variable $t$, and the problem is always feasible (${\Omega}(t)$ is non-empty).

Is then ${\Omega}(t)$ continous? (i.e. both upper and lower hemicontinuous, see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity))

*(Bonus question: 
Can I use the implicit function theorem to show this?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(e_i)_i$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here $rank(A(t))=m$ is constant and $m\leq n$.

When $A$ is continuous, its Moore-Penrose inverse $A^+$ is (in general) not continuous, except in our case; indeed

$A^+=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$ is clearly continuous. Note that a particular solution of $Ax=b$ is $x_0(t)=A^+(t)b$ and that $x_0$ is continuous.

Moreover, the eigenspace  $\ker(A)$ has a fixed dimension $n-m$; then, it has locally (but also if $t\in [a,b]$), a continuous basis $\{f_1(t),\cdots,f_{n-m}(t)\}$. Let $f_i(t)=\sum_ju_{j,i}(t)e_j$ where the $u_{i,j}$ are continuous and $U=[u_{j,i}]\in M_{n,n-m}$ has rank $n-m$, then, is injective.

Thus the general solution of $Ax=b$ in $t$ is

$A(t)^{-1}b=\{x_0(t)+\sum_i y_if_i(t);y=(y_i)_i\in\mathbb{R}^{n-m}\}$.

Now $\Omega(t)=A(t)^{-1}b\cap (]c_1,c_2[)^n=$

$\{x_0(t)+\sum_j(U(t)y)_je_j;\text{ for every }j\leq n,$

$(U(t)y)_j\in ]c_1-x_{0,j}(t),c_2-x_{0,j}(t)[\;\}$.

Since $\Omega(t)$ is non-empty and $U(t)$ is injective continuous, the set $K(t)$ of the admissible $y$ is the intersection of $n$ open "sandwiches" and, consequently, $K(t)$ is an open bounded convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$, the edge of which depending continuously on $t$.

Finally, $\Omega(t)=x_0(t)+U(t)K(t)$  and is continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty.